# Group by index + column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has two columns, `user_id` and `item_bought`.
Here `user_id` is the index of the dataframe. I want to group by both `user_id` and `item_bought` and get the item wise count for the user.

How do I do that?

Comment: You should be able to do `df.groupby([df.index, 'item_bought']).apply(pd.Series.count(level=0))`, actually doesn't `df.groupby([df.index, 'item_bought']).count()` give you what you want?

Comment: Why don't use make this an answer?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to group by [df.index, '<col_name>']: Grouper and axis must be same length

Comment: Different error for me: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Int64Index'`

Comment: @EdChum, great! It is not even documented, is it?

Answer (score 67):

From version [0.20.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements) it is simplier:

> Strings passed to **DataFrame.groupby()** as the **by** parameter may now reference either column names or index level names

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['first', 'second'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'B': np.arange(8)}, index=index)

print (df)

              A  B
first second      
bar   one     1  0
      two     1  1
baz   one     1  2
      two     1  3
foo   one     2  4
      two     2  5
qux   one     3  6
      two     3  7

print (df.groupby(['second', 'A']).sum())
          B
second A   
one    1  2
       2  4
       3  6
two    1  4
       2  5
       3  7
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it also for a `pd.Series`? I try to pass the Series name but it gives a `KeyError`. I mean, group a series by one of the index levels *and* by the value of the series.

Answer (score 46):

this should work:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,(6, 2)), columns=['col1','col2'])
>>> df['ind1'] = list('AAABCC')
>>> df['ind2'] = range(6)
>>> df.set_index(['ind1','ind2'], inplace=True)
>>> df

           col1  col2
ind1 ind2            
A    0        3     2
     1        2     0
     2        2     3
B    3        2     4
C    4        3     1
     5        0     0


>>> df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),'col1']).count()

           col2
ind1 col1      
A    2        2
     3        1
B    2        1
C    0        1
     3        1
```

I had the same problem using one of the columns from multiindex. with multiindex, you cannot use df.index.levels[0] since it has only distinct values from that particular index level and will be most likely of different size than whole dataframe...

check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html - get_level_values "Return vector of label values for requested level, equal to the length of the index"

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

In [11]:

df = pd.DataFrame()

In [12]:

df['user_id'] = ['b','b','b','c']

In [13]:

df['item_bought'] = ['x','x','y','y']

In [14]:

df['ct'] = 1

In [15]:

df

Out[15]:
    user_id     item_bought     ct
0   b   x   1
1   b   x   1
2   b   y   1
3   c   y   1
In [16]:

pd.pivot_table(df,values='ct',index=['user_id','item_bought'],aggfunc=np.sum)

Out[16]:

user_id  item_bought
b        x              2
         y              1
c        y              1
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It does exactly what they want.

Comment: it doesn't show how to get from an index + a column to the counts... in your example user_id is a column

Comment: just reset the index `df = df.reset_index()`... then you can use it in a pivot

Answer (score 1):

*I had the same problem* - imported a bunch of data and I wanted to groupby a field that was the index. I didn't have a multi-index or any of that jazz and nor do you.

I figured the problem is that the field I want is the index, so at first I just reset the index - but this gives me a useless index field that I don't want.  So now I do the following (two levels of grouping):

```
grouped = df.reset_index().groupby(by=['Field1','Field2'])
```

then I can use 'grouped' in a bunch of ways for different reports

```
grouped[['Field3','Field4']].agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

(which was what I wanted, giving me Field4 and Field3 averages, grouped by Field1 (the index) and Field2

For you, **if you just want to do the count of items per user**, in one simple line using groupby, the code could be

```
df.reset_index().groupby(by=['user_id']).count()
```

If you want to do more things then you can (like me) create 'grouped' and then use that. As a beginner, I find it easier to follow that way.

Please note, that the "reset_index" is not 'in place' and so will not mess up your original dataframe