# Pivoting data pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pivot this data:

```
         ID
UserID
1        a1
1        a2
2        a1
2        a3
```

into a dataframe like:

```
UserID   a1   a2   a3
1        1    1    0
2        1    0    1
```

I've tried doing the following `df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='UserID', columns='ID'`, but it gives me a `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` error. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First column is `index`, so is necessary change `index='UserID'` to `index=df.index`.

Also aggregate function is [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, columns=df['ID'], aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
print (df)
ID      a1  a2  a3
UserID            
1        1   1   0
2        1   0   1
```

Solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.index,df['ID'])
print (df)
ID     a1  a2  a3
row_0            
1       1   1   0
2       1   0   1
```

Or ([pandas 0.20.1+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43821531/2901002)) solution - [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` and column together, aggregate `size` and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['UserID','ID']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
ID      a1  a2  a3
UserID            
1        1   1   0
2        1   0   1
```

pandas bellow 0.20.1 solution - convert index to column by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby(['UserID','ID']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
ID      a1  a2  a3
UserID            
1        1   1   0
2        1   0   1
```

EDIT:

It seems index can be selected by index name too (not sure if it works bellow 0.20.1):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='UserID', columns='ID', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
print (df)
ID      a1  a2  a3
UserID            
1        1   1   0
2        1   0   1
```