# Sorting a multiindex dataframe by column without losing the order of indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` that has this structure:

```
1_product_id        2_product_id        1_qty_sold              2_qty_sold              times_sold
5584                4384                159.00                  653.00                  153
7889                2970                104.00                  497.00                  102
5024                2970                89.00                   413.00                  87
2990                8310                71.00                   283.00                  71
2990                4384                71.00                   282.00                  68
2990                2970                62.00                   240.00                  58
5584                8310                56.00                   208.00                  54
```

I am trying to make it look like this:

```
1_product_id        2_product_id        1_qty_sold              2_qty_sold              times_sold
5584                4384                159.00                  653.00                  153
                    8310                56.00                   208.00                  54
7889                2970                104.00                  497.00                  102
5024                2970                89.00                   413.00                  87
2990                8310                71.00                   283.00                  71
                    4384                71.00                   282.00                  68
                    2970                62.00                   240.00                  58
```

Where it is sorted by `times_sold`  and grouped by `1_product_id` and `2_product_id`. I tried:

```
df_out.groupby(['1_product_id','2_product_id']).sum() \ 
                                               .sort_values('times_sold', ascending = False)
```

But this messes up the `1_prodct_id` index:

```
                                            1_qty_despatched        2_qty_despatched    times_sold
1_product_id        2_product_id            
5584                4384                    159.00                  653.00              153
7889                2970                    104.00                  497.00              102
5024                2970                    89.00                   413.00              87
2990                8310                    71.00                   283.00              71
                    4384                    71.00                   282.00              68
                    2970                    62.00                   240.00              58
5584                8310                    56.00                   208.00              54
```

How can I sort it by `times_sold` and group by `1_product_id & 2_product_id` without losing the desired structure? I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925079/group-by-index-column-in-pandas) but it did not help me.

**Edit**

I tried:

```
df_out.groupby(['1_product_id','2_product_id']).sum() \ 
                                               .sort_values('times_sold', ascending = False) \
                                               .sort_index(0, ascending = False)
```

But the index is not in the order that I would like.

```
                                        1_qty_sold              2_qty_sold              times_sold
1_product_id        2_product_id            
7889                2970                104.00                  497.00                  102 # this should be the 2nd index
5584                4384                159.00                  653.00                  153 # this should be the 1st index
                    8310                56.00                   208.00                  54 
5024                2970                89.00                   413.00                  87 # this should be the 3rd index
2990                4384                71.00                   282.00                  68 # this should be the 4th index
                    2970                62.00                   240.00                  58
                    8310                71.00                   283.00                  71
```

After using [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) solution I get:

```
                                            times_sold  1_qty_sold  2_qty_sold
1_product_id        2_product_id            
5584                4384                    153         159.00      653.00
7889                2970                    102         104.00      497.00
5024                2970                    87          89.00       413.00
2990                8310                    71          71.00       283.00
                    4384                    68          71.00       282.00
                    2970                    58          62.00       240.00
5584                8310                    54          56.00       208.00
```

While I am trying to make it look like this:

```
# note that the last row is now the second row and indexes `1_product_id` is unique.

                                            times_sold  1_qty_sold  2_qty_sold
1_product_id        2_product_id            
5584                4384                    153         159.00      653.00
                    8310                    54          56.00       208.00 
7889                2970                    102         104.00      497.00
5024                2970                    87          89.00       413.00
2990                8310                    71          71.00       283.00
                    4384                    68          71.00       282.00
                    2970                    58          62.00       240.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For prevent sorting in `groupby` add `sort=False` with dict for original order for mapping:

```
print (df_out)
   1_product_id  2_product_id  1_qty_sold  2_qty_sold  times_sold
0          5584          4384       159.0       653.0          10 <- changed for test sort
1          7889          2970       104.0       497.0         102
2          5024          2970        89.0       413.0          87
3          2990          8310        71.0       283.0          71
4          2990          4384        71.0       282.0          68
5          2990          2970        62.0       240.0          58
6          5584          8310        56.0       208.0          54


uniq = {v: k for k, v in dict(enumerate(df_out['1_product_id'].unique())).items()}
print(uniq)
{5584: 0, 7889: 1, 5024: 2, 2990: 3}

df = (df_out.groupby(['1_product_id','2_product_id'], sort=False)
            .sum()
            .sort_values(['1_product_id', 'times_sold'],
                          key=lambda x: x.map(uniq).fillna(x), 
                          ascending=[True, False])

            )

print (df)
                           1_qty_sold  2_qty_sold  times_sold
1_product_id 2_product_id                                    
5584         8310                56.0       208.0          54
             4384               159.0       653.0          10
7889         2970               104.0       497.0         102
5024         2970                89.0       413.0          87
2990         8310                71.0       283.0          71
             4384                71.0       282.0          68
             2970                62.0       240.0          58
```

Alternative with another `groupby`:

```
df = (df_out.groupby(['1_product_id','2_product_id'], sort=False)
            .sum()
            .groupby('1_product_id', sort=False, group_keys=False)
            .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('times_sold', ascending=False))
            )

print (df)
                           1_qty_sold  2_qty_sold  times_sold
1_product_id 2_product_id                                    
5584         8310                56.0       208.0          54
             4384               159.0       653.0          10
7889         2970               104.0       497.0         102
5024         2970                89.0       413.0          87
2990         8310                71.0       283.0          71
             4384                71.0       282.0          68
             2970                62.0       240.0          58
```

Comment: But this sorts `id_s` which I do not want to sort, I want to group by them, because in this sorts the `ids` as well and I am unable to match the desired output.

Comment: I updated my question, in your solution `5584` is the first and the last row, I am trying to make it so that it would only be mentioned once, as in `groupby('1_product_id ')` so that it would look as in my desired output.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I think I got it. Need sorting by original order in `1_product_id` like groups and per groups `times_sold`, correct? Answer was edited.

Comment: Yes, its perfect now, thank you! I thought this would be some easy solution but it looks like it's not that easy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After you are done with your processing you can just add

```
df_out.sort_index(0)
```

This will fix your first index sorting problem. Other ones will be already sorted based on times sold.

Comment: but this places index `7889` above index `5584` , but I want to sort the index by the highest value of `times_sold` followed by the rest of that indexes `times_sold` values.